# Apps Broken after changing Icon Themes?

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, crash

Been running Ubuntu 20.04 for five months, and after playing around for the millionth time with icon themes, my system reported "App X will close because of a crash", and Gnome Tweaks, Terminal, File Explorer and others closed, and their icons disappeared and are not able to be opened again. (icons for the top bar also disappeared except for the date, time and calendar?)
On other users other than my main one, all works fine. Rebotted the system, nothing. Full shutdown, also nothing. Cannot open the terminal to try to fix things. However my browsers and some games seem to work fine?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it, won't remove the post in case anyone has the same issue.
Most apps wouldn't open, including the gnome terminal. Luckily, the Ubuntu Software app was, so I installed the xfce terminal, which opened, and changed the icons through there, this did reset the icons back to normal.
The command I used was `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'icon theme name'`.
It appears that some weird bug happened with gnome tweaks where after changing the icons it did it "halfway", so it didn't apply to all icons, crashing itself.